# no identity-based policy allows the ssm:StartSession action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-ssm

I followed the [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/getting-started-restrict-access-quickstart.html) to create a Custom Policy to allow only `AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost` action to a bastion host.

This is the Policy I created and getting `AccessDeniedExcepton`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ssm:StartSession",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:**************:document/AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:**************:instance/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "EnableSSMSession"
        },
        {
            "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "DescribeEC2"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, if I set `Resource` to `*` for `ssm:StartSession` action I am able to start a session with `StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost`. Can you please guide me about what I am missing? I literally followed the simple examples from the guide. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We shouldn't use account IDs for AWS public documents that begins with `AWS-`. Here is the working version of policy statement

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ssm:StartSession",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1::document/AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:**************:instance/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "EnableSSMSession"
        },
        {
            "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "DescribeEC2"
        }
    ]
}
```